# How to update libcurl version used by R on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: r, curl, ubuntu-18.04, rcurl

Since I have to use the `sftp` protocol to retrieve some documents from a remote server I reinstalled the `curl` library with ssl.

The `curl --version` now correctly returns

```
curl 7.72.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl / 7.72.0 OpenSSL / 1.1.1 zlib / 1.2.11 brotli / 1.0.4 libidn2 / 2.0.4 libpsl / 0.19.1 (+ libidn2 / 2.0.4 ) libssh / 0.7.0 / openssl / zlib nghttp2 / 1.30.0 librtmp / 2.3
Release-Date: 2020-08-19
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS brotli GSS-API HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy IDN IPv6 Kerberos Largefile libz NTLM NTLM_WB PSL SPNEGO SSL TLS-SRP UnixSockets
```

and the `sftp` protocol is now enabled.

In `R` I tried to reinstall the `RCurl` package from source with `install.package('RCurl', type = 'source')` but the `libcurlVersion()` command keeps returning

```
[1] "7.58.0"
attr (, "ssl_version")
[1] "OpenSSL / 1.1.1"
attr (, "libssh_version")
[1] ""
attr (, "protocols")
 [1] "dict" "file" "ftp" "ftps" "gopher" "http" "https" "imap"
 [9] "imaps" "ldap" "ldaps" "pop3" "pop3s" "rtmp" "rtsp" "smb"
[17] "smbs" "smtp" "smtps" "telnet" "tftp"
```

where, as you can see, the library version is different from the one installed on the machine and the `sftp` protocol is not enabled.

How can I force `R` to use the correct `curl` version?

Comment: Sometimes removing the old package before installing fixes this kind of issue. `remove.packages("RCurl")` and then re-install.

Comment: @csgroen unfortunately removing the old package doesn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-install Older curl to solve the issue.  You can specify the version of curl what you want, the guide build curl by source code
exampe:

```
wget https://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.58.0.zip
```

The guide to re-install curl by zip

https://yannmjl.medium.com/how-to-manually-update-curl-on-ubuntu-server-899476062ad6

Comment: You can specify the version of curl what you want, the guide build curl by source code
exampe:
wget https://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.58.0.zip

Comment: this is not about installing an old version of curl. The point is to force R to use the actual version of curl installed on the machine.

Comment: 1. install R 2. uninstall curl 3. install older version of curl, a little suggestion

Comment: The OP isn't trying to downgrade their curl installation to match what R is pointing to, they're trying to get R to point to the correct version of curl